# CSS3 gradient background

Tags: css

Is this right to apply gradient background to the body from a light shade of grey to white from bottom to top?

```css
body {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, bottom, top, from(#e7e7e7, to(#ffffff));
}
```

Comment: it displays plain white and I using the lates version of Chrome :O

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WbHCd/) to support all capable browsers

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#999999));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #999999);
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #999999);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #999999);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #999999);
}
```

[CSS3 Please](http://css3please.com/) might be useful

Comment: hi why do you need to set the height to 100%? it works, in fact my browser would siplay blocks of gradient and not the full page...

Comment: it shows you blocks of gradient because you have some content on the page. If it's empty (like in the JSFIddle) then it shows no BG http://jsfiddle.net/WbHCd/1/. I've added it just to show that it works.

Answer (score 1):

To Zoltan's solution, you could also add:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#999999');
```

to support older IE browsers.

Comment: And then you need to insure that you remove the filter for some older browsers, such as IE9.