# CSS - Colour blend gradient - Is this possible?

Tags: css, gradient

I would like to know if this is possbile using CSS only. Choose the hex values of two colours and then blend them in a gradient like way, just like the visual here:

[image]

I look forward to your ideas? Thanks for your time.
Graham

Comment: Using css3, yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719019/css3-gradient-background

Comment: Or you could use whatever Jnatalzia picked for you... why is he getting a downvote anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### you can do a **[CSS3 gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)**.

here is a quick example from one of the online [gradient generators](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/):

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7f1919 0%, #207cca 100%, #2989d8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7f1919), color-stop(100%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#2989d8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7f1919 0%,#207cca 100%,#2989d8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7f1919 0%,#207cca 100%,#2989d8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #7f1919 0%,#207cca 100%,#2989d8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7f1919 0%,#207cca 100%,#2989d8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7f1919', endColorstr='#2989d8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mbmm9/)

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @Jonathan was the quickest I could put it into the example ^_^